# "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an error in FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION in Eclipse which says Cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Below are my coding:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), newactivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you.

Comment: this has been introduced in API level 5. What is the API level you are working with?